# Add existing wallet to geth with address and password

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, import, console

A few months ago I mined some Ethereum. I do not have the .json file anymore. But I do have the address and the password. Currently I'm running Geth (for the past 12 hours) but I'm not able to put in any commands. For some reason it keeps syncing.

- How can I write commands in Geth?
- How can I add an existing wallet with address and password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to access your account without the private key which is not the same as the password.

Your private key is stored in the `keystore` directory within the Ethereum data directory (per default `~/.ethereum` on Linux).
It should look something like this:

`UTC--2015-09-21T16-54-52.729410400Z--05936944f0d93499f636a0dfa5e71399a0cc3fca`

i.e., a UTC time stamp followed by your public address. This file contains your private key, encrypted with your password.

See
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts
for more information on keystores and how to import private keys.

Comment: The link provided is no active anymore. Use this one: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/account-management

Answer (score 2):

Regarding commands - run your Geth instance using:

```
geth [options] console 2>>geth.log
```

or you can start two instances:

```
geth [options]
geth [options] attach
```

when the second one allows you to enter commands.

Answer (score 2):

To add an existing private key:
Save it in an plain text file, with only the key in the 1st line followed by a newline, then:

```
geth account import <keyfile>
```

Imports an unencrypted private key from < keyfile> and creates a new account and prints the address.

From: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#creating-an-account-by-importing-a-private-key